# Is it possible to have alternating colors in Windows 7 Explorer windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, user-experience, desktop-customization

I know this is doable in Winforms and WPF, but not sure if I can do it for explorer windows. Something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure, perhaps it's possible using a shell extension. If you can't find one you'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, sort of. Of course, it would be best to ditch Windows Explorer as a whole and move on to another file manager of your chosing. Most of the alternative file managers can do this.

If you wanna stick with Windows Explorer, the extension [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) offers this functionality. There's a [screenshot](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2077177/Jing/tweaks.png) available clearly offering this option. Looks like it does what you want but I don't know if it works with Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks I only need it for Win 7. What other win explorers are there? I never heard of any since XP where the integration and performance wasn't fast.

Comment: @Joan Venge It's impossible to list them all. I'm using both [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) and [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/). Also popular are [xplorer2](http://www.zabkat.com/), [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir), [Nomad.NET](http://www.nomad-net.info/), and [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), of course.

Answer (score -1):

There are some extensions the provide it.

I found a whole list here: http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-explorer-addons.htm

Comment: -1: You haven't specified anything that answers the OP's question, and you linked to a list that's unmaintained and lists extensions for XP.

Comment: NO it does not list extensions just for XP, it mentions QTTABBar for Windows 7 (as the other answer from JC2K8 above) as well as shortcomings for QTTABBAR so also provides other alternatives. And since it is a top 100 site... In this case that would be handier than to copy and paste the complete list in this answer.